# Performance of Sorting Output of Database (python/sqlite)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm writing a function to output certain fields of data within a database, based on a provided sort key. The key signals to the function if the output should be sorted by either title, year or budget (these are the only 3 attributes which need to be displayed).

Example database:

```
ID  | name | year | budget    | other fields
---------------------------------------------
id1 | foo  | 2020 | 50000000  | xxx
id2 | bar  | 1997 | 200000    | yyy
id3 | baz  | 2016 | 3333333   | zzz
...
```

Currently, I'm using the following code to do this:

```
def db_output(sort_key: str) -> None:
    # ...
    CURSOR.execute("SELECT * FROM movies")
    output = CURSOR.fetchall()
    CONN.close()

    clean_table = [x for x in output if x[3] is not None]
    sorted_list = sorted(
        clean_table, key=lambda x: x[{"title": 1, "year": 2, "budget": 3}[sort_key]]
    )
    # Output clause
```

My question is would it be more efficient to use the ORDER BY command to retrieve the sorted data rather than sorting it in python as shown above? I do not need to actually organize the database, just provide a sorted output to the user. Forgive my lack of knowledge here, I'm confused after reading about "stable" vs "unstable" sorting and the like.

Comment: The only way to tell is to benchmark the two methods.

Comment: Adding an ORDER BY clause to the query will almost certainly be more efficient.